# Sqoop Incremental Import with no Primary Key

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import data from MYSQL to Hive table using incremental import. But my table has no primary key. I had created a sqoop job.

Sample  MYSQL table Data

```
| Oct-14 |   581 |
| Nov-14 |   519 |
| Dec-14 |   605 |
| Jan-15 |   484 |
| Feb-15 |   584 |
| Mar-15 |   684 |
 Mar-15    684
```

First column is of String datatype and second is INT.

My Sqoop Job is

```
sqoop job \
--create test13 \
-- import \
--append \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/tractor_sales --username root --P \
--query 'SELECT t.*,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM tractor_sales t,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r where $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by year \
--merge-key @rownum \
--check-column @rownum \
--hive-database salesforecast --hive-table tractor_sales \
--incremental append  \
--last-value 0 \
--hive-import \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/test;
```

when trying to execute the job I am getting the following error

> 'Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: Could you please post the mysql table schema name as well ?

Comment: @SandeepSingh

Feilds: year,sales 
DataType : year   (Varchar(10))
                   sales (INT(11))

Comment: `split-by` can only be perform with integer column. Please change it with sales.

Comment: Sometimes I have faced the count issue with rownum so validate the result carefully.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Thanks for your input.The values in sales column can be repetitive, i mean to say i can get same values for two or more months. Does using the --split-by for sales still suffice my requirement.

Comment: Yes, there wont be any issue.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Here the error is related to the query i had used. if i had removed the --query and and used --table instead. my --merge-key and and --check-column will be changed to sales. when i had created a sqoop job and executed, it is creating boundary values. For example in the existing data Maximum value of sales is 800. it is storing the value is metastore, if new rows are inserted with 700,850,900, it is taking the values of 850 and 900 ignoring 700.

Comment: it should not ignore, however I recommend to go with one mapper for incremental import.